# What connections between computer science and ergodic theory?

Tags: computer-science, entropy, ergodic-theory

I have a background in ergodic theory, but I am switching to computer science/programming.

I would like to know if tools from ergodic theory could be useful, especially something around coding of ergodic transformation with a finite measurable partition, which seems to have some computer science flavor. What literature do you recommend at the intersection of these two fields?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but genetic algorithms are in essence strongly related to dynamical systems (in simple cases it's just a Markov chain). Ergodicity of such system corresponds to important property - so-called asymptotic correctness - roughly, guarantee of exploring the whole solution space, eventually. I've heard good opinions about [book by M. Vose](http://www.amazon.com/The-Simple-Genetic-Algorithm-Foundations/dp/026222058X)

Comment: Coming from Computer Science, but now studying  ergodic theory, I wonder about the same thing. Perhaps hashing could be an interesting field, as it also concerns with perturbation of things...